# Computation of an integral using change of variables

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

So the integral I am trying to compute is:

$$\int\limits_B \exp(x+y)dxdy$$

where $B=\{(x,y)|\in \mathbb R|  |x|+|y| \leq 1 \}$

Help will be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other commenters have mentioned, your region is bounded between the lines $x+y=1$, $x+y=-1$, $x-y=1$, $x-y=-1$. Consider the change of variables $x+y=u$ and $x-y=v$. Then our region is simply the square where $u,v \in [-1,1]$. By the change of variable formula we have $dxdy=|J|dudv$ where $|J|$ is the absolute value of the determinant of

\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{bmatrix}

We can find $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ from our substitutions by considering $u-v$ and $u+v$ which yields $y=\frac{u+v}{2}$ and $x=\frac{u-v}{2}.$ Thus 
$$
|J|=
\left| 
\begin{array}{cc}
1/2 & 1/2 \\
-1/2 & 1/2
\end{array}
\right|
=
1/2.
$$
So 
$\int_B e^{x + y}dxdy = \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{e^{u}}{2}dudv = \int_{-1}^{1} e^{u}du = e - e^{-1} = 2\sinh(1).
$

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at what the region $B$ looks like:

[image: region B]

You can split this region into four regions (equlateral right triangles) of either [type I or type II](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DIGeneralRegion.aspx) (whichever you find easier; I'd suggest type I), and integrate the function over each separately, adding the results together at the end.

**EDIT:** As others have mentioned, it'd probably be even easier to split the diamond into two triangles, not four.

Comment: i can use your picture (+1)

Answer (score 5):

your region is a diamond $(0,-1),(-1,0), (0,1), (1,0)$, split up the integral into two parts, each part for giving for different type of bounds.
$$\int_{-1}^{0} \int_{-x-1}^{x+1} e^{x+y} \,dydx+\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x-1}^{-x+1} e^{x+y} \,dydx$$
you can use the figure on other answer. First part is for the left side of $y$-axis and second part if for the region on right side of $y$- axis.

Answer (score 3):

Drawing the region will help:

[image: Illustration of region B]

So you can see that you will need to break the integral up into two parts:

$$
\int_B e^{x + y}dxdy = \int_{-1}^0e^xdx\int_{-x - 1}^{x + 1}e^ydy + \int_{0}^1e^xdx\int_{x - 1}^{1 - x}e^ydy
$$

These integrals shouldn't introduce anything hard to integrate (tedious perhaps, but not difficult), as an example:

$$
\int_{-x - 1}^{x + 1}e^ydy = e^{x + 1} - e^{-x - 1}
$$

Then multiply by $e^x$ (or just add it to the exponent):

$$
\int_{-1}^0 e^x\left(e^{x + 1} - e^{-x - 1}\right)dx = \int_{-1}^0 \left(e^{2x + 1} - e^{- 1}\right)dx = \left.\frac{e^{2x + 1}}{2} - xe^{-1}\right|_{-1}^0 = \frac{e}{2} - \left(\frac{e^{-1}}{2} + e^{-1}\right) = \frac{e - 3e^{-1}}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

separate cases $x<0$ and $x>0$ and find the integration range for $y$ (the range depends on $x$) in both cases